# symfony2: how to config 2 proxy for amazon s3 and sns

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-s3, proxy, amazon-sns

I want to add a proxy for Amazon SNS service. From current config file, how to add more proxies?

config.yml:

```
aws:
    version: "latest"
    region: "%s3_region%"
    validate: false
    scheme: "http"
    http:
        proxy: "%s3_proxy%" //I want to add proxy for sns: "%sns_proxy%"
    credentials:
        key: "%s3_key%"
        secret: "%s3_secret%" 
    S3:
        version: '2006-03-01'
    SNS:
        version: '2010-03-31'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Thanks for sharing your config file. What is your question?

Comment: I want to add an proxy for amazon sns service. From current config file, how to add more proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Set another proxy for only snsclient:

```
 $options = [
  'region'            => $s3_region,
  'version'           => 'latest',
  'http'=>[
    'proxy'    => $sns_proxy, //this proxy for only snsclient
  ],
  'credentials' => [
    'key' => $s3_key,
    'secret' => $s3_secret,
  ]
];
$client = SnsClient::factory($options);
// Snsサーバに接続
$this->sns_topic = $sns_topic;
```